# How to disable the NSUndoManager in an NSDocument?

Tags: macos, nsdocument, nsundomanager

I'm using `NSDocument` but I would like to disable the undo manager.

**How can I do it?**

Comment: By reading the documentation:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/UndoArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000010i

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[- (BOOL)isUndoRegistrationEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000211-CJBDJBID)

**Return Value**

**YES** if registration is enabled; otherwise, *NO*.

and:

[- (void)disableUndoRegistration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000211-CHDBEBCE)

Disables the recording of undo operations, whether by registerUndoWithTarget:selector:object: or by invocation-based undo.